# Load JSON values every 60 seconds automatically in Android

Tags: android, json

I have developed one tab application.

There are 2 users, one user feeding data into it and it stored in remote database. Other user access those data in his tablet. But problem is that every time second user load JSON values manually, means it is not synchronise automatically.

I want it to be automatically. Means, for every 60 seconds new JSON values to be retrieved and stored in local storage area. And it don't disturb previous stored values.

Comment: There are multiple questions: 1. Load JSON , 2. Refresh every 60 seconds , 3. Store in Local Storage & Not to override previous stored values . What have you tried on the above 3 questions ?

Comment: This sounds like a simple threading solution. Have you done that? Can you please show us the code?

Comment: i thing you have to use service for this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Load JSON

Create New Calss **JSONPASER**

```
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
        import java.util.List;

        import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
        import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
        import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
        import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
        import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
        import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
        import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
        import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import android.util.Log;

        public class JSONParser {

        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONParser() {

        }

        // function get json from url
        // by making HTTP POST or GET method
        public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

in the existing class create an another inner class (async class)

```
    class AttemptJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("JSON Attempting ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Key", value));


            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                finish();
            startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

1. Refresh every 60 seconds

   ```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
       // call JSON methods here
       new AttemptJson ().execute();
         }
    }, 60000  );
   ```
2. Store in Local Storage

   ```
      JSONObject jOb = json; // json is ths object where u have crated in the class
   ```

Answer (score 0):

just call the JSON functions after 60 seconds using

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // call JSON methods here
    }
}, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

use thread to refresh every 60 seconds
and use unique values in local data base to store